# finding length of a sentence in a cell, in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new to this scripting and all, I want to find the length of a sentence in a cell in google sheet. Example,  "I want to check the length" is a sentence in cell A1 in google sheet, I want to find the length of this string.

And one more, if I want to replace text like space(" ") with any thing like plus (+), I have used script as shown below

```
var newdata = olddata.toString().replace(" ","+");

// here old data refers to the string "I want to check length"

// output that displayed in log is like "I+want to check length"

// Output, that I want i like "I+want+to+check+length"
```

when I used this, in log I can see only, first space is getting replaced in the whole string/sentence. so how can modify/alter my code in order to  replace all the spaces with any desired character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the string is given by `newString.length` property.

```js
let oldString = "I want to check the length";
console.log(oldString.length);
```

The [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function uses [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace the strings. To replaces all matched patters, you will need to use `/g` global match. To match all spaces, you need to provide `/\ /g` to the `replace()` function. See example:

```js
let oldString = "I want to check the length";
let newString = oldString.replace(/\ /g, "+");
console.log(newString);
console.log(newString.length);
```

Comment: Hi, I see some people use logger.log, and here you used console.log, may I know the major difference between these two functions

Comment: I do not use `google-apps-script`. But this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) suggests `Logger.log()` prints to the console. The function I used `console.log()` is in plain javascript. It does the same - prints to console.

Comment: Cool, I got you, seems like both the functions work same

Comment: Hey, one more question, is there a way to find out or eliminate extra spacing in a sentence through script

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by extra spacing? There is the [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) function that strips off white spaces from beginning and end of the string - if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: "I  want to check the length" here I want to eliminate extra spaces in between. and one more question adding to this about function trim(),

//lets suppose the range has this value getRange(2,3) = "I'm   Cool  "

var k = getRange(2,3).getValue(); k = k.trim(); //when I try trimming here, its not working, and the word is going with extra space

newk = k.toString().replace(/\ /g," +"); // I'm appending "+" globally, then I see that symbol is getting appended for extra space as well, where I'm eliminating it by using replace(" "," "); //so is there any other way around to get this sorted